# Apex removes \n from HTTP Response

Tags: visualforce, httpresponse, space

I am using google api. The expected response is

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "textAnnotations": [
        {
          "locale": "en",
          "description": "ABBEY\nROAD NW8\nCITY OF WESTMINSTER\n",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 45,
                "y": 43
              },
              {
                "x": 269,
                "y": 43
              },
              {
                "x": 269,
                "y": 178
              },
              {
                "x": 45,
                "y": 178
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

I am getting this type of response.

```
 {
  "responses": [
    {
      "textAnnotations": [
        {
          "locale": "en",
          "description": "ABBEY 
                          ROAD NW8 
                          CITY OF WESTMINSTER",
          "boundingPoly": {
            "vertices": [
              {
                "x": 45,
                "y": 43
              },
              {
                "x": 269,
                "y": 43
              },
              {
                "x": 269,
                "y": 178
              },
              {
                "x": 45,
                "y": 178
              }
            ]
          }
        },
```

Apex removes **\n** from the response. 
I tried

```
HttpResponse response = http.send(request); 

String strResponse = response.getBody();
strResponse.replaceAll('\n', '<br/>');
```

But it is not working Result shows in the same line

Comment: Are you displaying the response in `outputText' in Visualforce?

Comment: Yes I am displaying it in output text. I tried escape false but didnt work

Comment: Tried this?  `<apex:outputLabel value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(strResponse ), '\\n', '<br/>')}" escape="false"/ > `

Comment: awesome its working

Comment: @HemantJain Could be added as Answer so other's  can use it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try displaying the String with the help of `JSENCODE` and then replacing `\n` with `<br/>` tag.

Below is the sample code to display the string on VF page:

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(strResponse ), '\\n', '<br/>')}" escape="false"/ >
```